# Красная Армия или Красная армия: прописные буквы в составных названиях

Tags: прописная-строчная

Красная А(а)рмия – составное название, однако я встречаю самые разнообразные написания:

- Красная Армия
- Красная армия
- красная армия (хотя это, скорее уже экзотика и стилистика)

> Сильнейшая центральная власть и несомненная мощь красной армии — вот все «ergo sum» коллектива советской России. (Пришвин)

Первые два варианта, я думаю, в примерах не нуждаются.

На [грамоте.ру](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=236948) ответ "Красная армия" без обоснования. Хотя присутствует и [ответ "Красная Армия"](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=270004) в ответе на другой вопрос.

Примеры и варианты почерпнуты из обсуждения [на форуме грамоты.ру](http://forum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=6116), после прочтения которого я не стал лучше понимать, что правильно и, главное, почему.

Другой источник ([Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/24.htm#%D0%B7_12)) не упоминает Красную а(А)рмию, однако говорит о зарубежных:

> Примечание 1. С прописной буквы пишутся некоторые названия зарубежных армий, например: Войско Польское, Армия Крайова, Армия Людова.

При поиске здесь, просмотрел несколько вопросов, не нашел ни конкретно этого примера, ни руководства к тому как решить вопрос.

Также предполагаю, что "Советская А(а)рмия" будет следовать тем же правилам.

Comment: Вот такой ещё есть, более официальный ответ: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=300442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, сейчас мы должны ориентироваться  на свод правил РАН и на Орфографический словарь Лопатина, который рекомендует:

> Сов'етская 'армия
>
> Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус.
>   яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин
>   (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.

https://lopatin.academic.ru/135755/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F

Раньше в справочнике Розенталя мы могли прочесть такое:

> В соответствии с традицией все слова в названиях высших
>   государственных учреждений и общественных организаций России, а также
>   бывшего Советского Союза пишутся с прописной буквы, например:
>   Верховный Совет РФ, Совет Федерации, Верховный Суд России, Совет
>   Министров, Объединенные Вооруженные Силы СНГ.
>
> Примечание 2. Но в написании некоторых новых названий наблюдаются
>   колебания, например: Федеральное собрание (Федеральное Собрание),
>   Государственная дума (Государственная Дума), Конституционный суд
>   (Конституционный Суд).

В связи с заметным снижением патетики соответствующего названия, писать "Советская Армия" сейчас не рекомендуется, но если мы, полностью сохраняя орфографию прошлого наименования праздника, напишем "День Советской Армии..." (приурочив это к дате 23 февраля), то ошибки не будет. Мы в точности передаём тот текст, который был принят в течение многих лет.

В учебниках истории (кстати, даже в пределах одной книги) тоже встречается разнобой - то со строчной,
 то с прописной.

В Советской исторической энциклопедии прописные буквы:

> Советская Армия — Термин, заменивший название Красная Армия (с февраля
>   1946); под ним понимаются все виды Вооружённых Сил (См. Вид  вооружённых сил) СССР, кроме ВМФ. Об истории С. А. см. 24-й том БСЭ,
>   книга II — «СССР», раздел Вооружённые силы. Большая советская
>   энциклопедия

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/orthography_lopatin/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2

Так что колебания в написании пока остались - если речь о прошлой исторической эпохе или о названии прошлого праздника, то пишем по традиции с большой буквы оба слова, если имеем в виду именно официальное название военной организации, то Красная армия, Советская армия. Если в бытовом смысле: пошёл в армию, но если имеется в виду исполнение долга перед Родиной, то всё-таки официально: "служба в Советской армии", о прошлой эпохе - "служил в Красной армии".